# MS Access Listbox shows only one record when its recordset is set to an ADODB recordset from Sqlite

Tags: ms-access, listbox, adodb, ms-access-2016, recordset

I tried to update a Listbox  with a command button click on MS Access form with an ADODB recordset to Sqlite database file.
The recordset RecordCount property returns 100 records correctly, but the Listbox only shows the first row/record in the recordset when the code is run.
What is wrong, and what I have been missing about this Listbox??! I appreciate your help.
Here is the code:

```
Private Sub cdRefresh_Click()
    Dim Cnn As Object, Rst As Object
    Dim cnString As String, SqlStr As String
    
    cnString = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=E:\Sample Data\Sales1.db"
    Set Cnn = VBA.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    SqlStr = "Select * From Sales Limit 100;"
    Cnn.Open cnString
    Set Rst = VBA.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    With Rst
        Set .ActiveConnection = Cnn
        .Source = SqlStr
        .LockType = 3 '' adLockOptimistic
        .CursorType = 1 '' adOpenKeyset
        .Open
    End With
    Debug.Print "records #"; Rst.RecordCount '' despite RecordCount>1 , the listbox only shows one record
    With Me.List0
        .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
        .ColumnCount = Rst.Fields.Count
        .ColumnHeads = True
        Set .Recordset = Rst
    End With
    Set Rst = Nothing
    Set Cnn = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I don't think setting a listbox. *recordset* will get you anywhere. I think you need to set its rowsource. The recordset would only present a single record at that point, the first one.

Comment: Try a quick `rst.MoveLast` and `rst.MoveFirst` to make sure the entire recordset is loaded and the pointer is at the first record. @Minty That's not true, setting the recordset of a listbox is a valid thing to do, and is often desirable when using external databases (saves you from making lots of passthrough queries)

Comment: I'll stand corrected, I've never seen that property used like that before. As usual - learn something every day.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all who commented and made a contribution here.
I could solve my problem by adding this property to the set of properties of ADODB.Recordset on above code;

```
Rst.CursorLocation = 3 '' adUseClient
```

The default value for CursorLocation is 2 "adUseServer", and mostly determined by Connection type.